# Center focused slider

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider

I need to do both on the design but I can't do it in any way.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cR11N.png)
Who is a professional in this topic help. I tried it with swiper slider, but it didn't work out.

That's what I get with swiper slider [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YUPYe.jpg)
That's code '''https://codepen.io/bilolisroilovv/pen/rNeePvX'''

The problem is that if you increase the width of the center element, it comes out.

How can I solve this problem? Or try any other ready-made option!

Answer (score 0):

for this purpose you should decrease number of `slidesPerView:`.
for example in this size you should set `slidesPerView: 2`.

Comment: I need to do exactly as in the design. Your option is not suitable.

Comment: because you give 500px to center item, it pushes other elemnts for getting more space. in this case you should customize swiper js code that i think is not prperly wat.

Comment: I understand. Can't help how to do exactly as in the design? Edit my code in codepen